# latex hbt! not working, jumping to next page

Tags: floats, sectioning, box

I'm using overleaf as my latex editor. I'm using `hbt!` for here, below the page, top of the page. But my page jumps to another page. My code looks something like this:

```
\chapter{Train and Comparison}

\section{Validation Mean IoU with Early-Stopping}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
  \centering

  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
```

And it results:
[image: latex hbt! not working]

Here is the output PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pQstTtI1G0so7Qc1u-t1lF5IcbDYqpoS/view?usp=sharing

Here is my complete code: https://pastebin.com/a8AiDCpz

And I'm using this template: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/thesis

And another problem is the top section name is wrong, I don't want to fix it. I just want to remove it, as for some pages when the section name is too long, it doesn't even appear. I know there is a way to assign a short name to a section, sub-section. But in my case, there is no short name. So removing it would be better.

Comment: that is working as expected, the effect of `[hbt]` is to remove the `p` option so preventing the float appearing on a page of its own, but as it does not fit this is eventually forced on to a page on its own by the end of the document.

Comment: please do not use external links, make a small but complete document and add inline to your question (you can use `example-image` as the image) the question is archived here forever and will not make sense if that google drive and pastebin links break.

Comment: possibly you just want to remove the `\resizebox`. It is making the figure too large to fit under the heading and making the caption  text look unnaturally small.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added all the necessary info here, but sometimes other portion of the code is required... that's why I added them...

Comment: No. Examples really should be complete small documents that show the problem, but here I can not see what you think the problem is. looking at your image the figure is too large to go under the heading so the next page is the first place it can go, or make the figure smaller so it does fit. start by removing the `\resizebox`

Comment: note that `\chapter` prevents top floats on the chapter opening page